# icon_map in PHP annotation instead of layouts.yml

Tags: 8, layout-builder

I need to add an Icon to a layout added by a contrib module. But I see it is adding the layout via plugin PHP file instead of layouts.yml.
The annotation looks like following

```
/**
 * A very advanced custom layout.
 *
 * @Layout(
 *   id = "lb_tabs_tabs",
 *   label = @Translation("Tabs"),
 *   category = @Translation("Effects"),
 *   path = "layouts/tabs",
 *   template = "lb-tabs-tabs",
 *   icon_map = ""
 * )
 */
```

I don't know how to represent the multidimensional array into this annotation form. When I tried simple `[['region', 'region']]` form it errored `[Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got  '['` .

tried `@Array(@Array('region', 'region'))` as well but got

`Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '('` .

What is the correct way to add an icon_map there?

Also tried adding `layouts.yml` and moving these values to yml and the layout option just disappeared as a whole`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the layout alter hook ( `hook_layout_alter(&$definitions)` ).  The definitions variable is an array of all the defined layouts keyed by the layout machine name.

The value here is a `Drupal\Core\Layout\LayoutDefinition` object.  This has a setIconMap method.  You can pass this an array of arrays that define the icon.

E.g. if the yml format is:

```
- [top]
- [first, second]
- [bottom]
```

the value is something like:

```
$map = [
  ['top'],
  ['first', 'second'],
  ['bottom']
]
```